# Get properties for single dbid fails to return data status 202

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

this issue is happening since today morning. Same code/endpoint used yesterday and was working perfectly.
example:

```
'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/::urn::/metadata/:::guid:/properties?objectid=3981'
```

keeps returning 202 status code even after 20 retries in some tries it returns 504 as well.

**Update 1: currently its 202 in endless retires.**

**Update 2: (possible workaround)**

- Tried the Following: downloaded and reuploaded the model to a different bim 360 project (works) - same file
- Reuploaded the same file as a revision on the the original file (works)

Currently I am happy it works, but need to know what is the cause of this issue, to prevent it in the future.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rami, can you check your Forge subscription is still active?

Comment: Hi @JaimeRosales yes its active till Dec 2021 annual renewal

Comment: Can you still load your model in the Viewer? Is the translation hosted in a persistent bucket? maybe is not and that's why is not available anymore.

Comment: @JaimeRosales yes I can load and view the model, its stored on BIM 360 not a private forge bucket. That is where the call is originating (by selecting the object in the viewer)

Comment: @JaimeRosales thanks for the insights, after checking everything else i checked if the model or bim 360 is the issue. I updated the question with my findings (and a possible workaround).